# как распечатать массив php в html файле

Tags: php, html, массивы, echo

Пытаюсь распечатать массив php на странице html, каждый элемент с новой строки, новая строка устанавливается html тегом. Проблема в том, что почему-то, код после тега не воспринимается как код php и печатается прямо на странице. Как лучше распечатать, чтобы ничего лишнего не было. По заданию, главная страница должна быть именно html.
Задание: отсортировать массив строк, исходный порядок строк отображается цветом.

```
        <div id="result" class= "T">
            <h2>Начальный порядок строк:</h2>

            <span><font size="7">
                 <?php  
                   echo implode( "  <br>  \r\n ",  $MYarr);
                ?>
            </font></span>
            

            <h2>Порядок строк поле сортировки:</h2>
            <span><font size="7">
                <?php  
                   echo implode(  " <br> \r\n     ", $result); 
                ?>
            </font></span>

        </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы распечатать в html странице, надо заставить сервер обрабатывать php код в html странице, т.е. поковыряться в настройках apache2 или что у вас там

Comment: у меня Apache 2.4 опенсервер

Comment: ну вот значит там, в районе `OpenServer\userdata\config\КАКОЙ-ТО-APACHE_server.conf` в районе `<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">`  писать ещё html......... хотя как по мне возможно в задании имеется в виду, что файл должен содержать html а не быть сам по себе html, либо на текущей странице php не должно быть...потому что это бестолково иметь html и интерпретировать его как php

Comment: Просто препод сказал, что файл должен называться task.html. Он его будет запускать на сервере ВУЗа.

Comment: ясно. ок. см. коммент выше

Comment: <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
      SSLOptions          +StdEnvVars
       html
   </FilesMatch>

Comment: ну как бэ.... строка `cgi|shtml|phtml|php` не для красоты там)

Comment: спасибо, но ошибка не ушла(  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|html|php)$">

Comment: перезагрузи сервер.....или ты просто не в том файле редачил...надо в настройках посмотреть какой именно апач сейчас загружается ибо их там ожно выбирать разные

Comment: Все правильно вроде, приложил скрин, сервер перезагрузил, ошибка не ушла. Что-то мне кажется, что изменения на моем сервере не отразятся у препода. Может, мне лучше переписать алгоритм печати массива, но как-нибудь без использования тегов хтмл....